# Commit Changes after DataGridView edit using LINQ2SQL (Winforms)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, commit, dataview

Given a DataGridView that has a BindingSource set like this:

On a winform, we add a BindingSource object using the designer, called myBindingScource.
Then on the Form.Designer.cs we add this to the InitializeComponents()

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(MyLinq.Person); //Mylinq is the autogenerated Linq Model/Diagram
```

Later, in the form itself we do:

```
myDataView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

and then we have a method that populates the Grid…

```
using ( myDataContext mdc = new MyDataContext() )
{
    myDataView.DataSource = from per in mdc.person
                            select per;
}
```

As an aside note, I've set up the columns in Design Time, and everything shows ok.
Since the LINQ 2 SQL is not returning an Anonymous, the "myDataView" is editable, and here comes the question…

Question is: **how do I persist those changes?**

There are dozens of events in the datagrid, and I'm not sure which one is more appropriate. Even if I try one of the events, I still don't know what is the code I need to execute to send those changes back to the DB in order to persist the changes.

I remember back in the ADO.NET DataSet days, you would do dataadapter.Update(dataset);

Also imagine that both the retrieve and the persist() are on a Business Layer and the method signature looks like this:

```
public void LoadMyDataGrid(DataGridView grid);
```

that method takes the form's grid and populates it using the LINQ2SQL query shown above.

Now I'd like to create a method like this:

```
public void SaveMyDataGrid(DataGridView grid); // or similar
```

The idea is that this method is not on the same class (form), many examples tend to assume that everything is together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RowValidated event would be a good place to check to see if it's time to persist changes to the database.

```
    this.dataGridView1.RowValidated += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_RowValidated);

    private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MyLinq.Person person = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as MyLinq.Person;

        if (person != null)
        {
            // save this person back to data access layer
        }
    }
```

**After your edit:**

I wouldn't pass back a datagrid instance to your service layer. I'd pass back `IEnumerable<MyLinq.Person>` or `IList<MyLinq.Person>` then iterate over the collection in your service layer, and depending on the logic performed; persist the changes to the data access layer (your database)

Comment: I was interested in the "//save this person" part of the code.
I have a person object that came from the DB and was placed in a row. The row was edited. Now I want LINQ to put those changes back. In NHIBERNATE and others, there were ".save()" or ".persist()" methods on each Class/Object. But I don't know how to tell LINQ (by reading cloggings' sample below), to update the person object.

Comment: I have found the solution (Attach) here: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/17/117791.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The 'save' method on the DataContext object is `SubmitChanges()`.

```
using (MyContext c = new MyContext())
{
     var q = (from p in c.People
             where p.Id == 1
             select p).First();
     q.FirstName = "Mark";
     c.SubmitChanges();
}
```

As Michael G mentioned, you'll need to gather the changes, and pass them back to the bll object.

Comment: But if I have a People object that comes from a Row in the Datagrid, how can I tell the DataContext to update that "Person"? I remember in other OR Mappers each object had a .persist() or .save() method. 
The object retrieved from MichaelG's code is a "Person" object. I need to tell LINQ, go ahead and update this Person.

Comment: See the above comment, the solution is that I need to "attach" the disconnected object back, and I needed I timestamp.